# Duplicar valores con la función .resample en Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo unos datos que me gustaría repartirlos en formatos de una hora. El problema es que no tengo entradas todas las horas, por lo tanto, aunque lo reparte, hay valores que deja a cuando no quiero que ocurra; me explico mejor con el ejemplo:

**Datos**

Estos son los datos de 3 entradas.

```
data = {'fecha_entrada': ['2021-01-01 00:25:24.027', '2021-01-01 06:53:57.853', '2021-01-01 10:07:32.817'],
        'fecha_salida': ['2021-01-01 11:58:23.247', '2021-01-01 15:24:50.710', '2021-01-01 11:49:27.727'],
        'length': [11.3259, 8.3053, 1.4155],
        'dia_semana': [4, 4, 4],
        'laborable': [0, 0, 0],
        'festivo': [1, 1, 1],
        'entrada': [1, 1, 1]}

datos = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(data['fecha_entrada']))
datos.index.name = 'fecha_entrada'
datos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

**Resample**

```
# Agrupar los datos por Hora
datos = datos.resample(
    rule = '1H',
    axis = 0,
    closed = "left" #Qué lado del intervalo bin se cierra. El valor predeterminado es "izquierda" para todos los desplazamientos de frecuencia excepto para "M", "A", "Q", "BM", "BA", "BQ" y "W", que tienen un valor predeterminado de "derecha".
    
).agg(
    {
        "fecha_entrada":"first",
        "fecha_salida":"last",
        "length":"sum",
        "entrada":"sum",
        "dia_semana":"first",
        "laborable":"first",
        "festivo":"first"
    }
).fillna(0)
datos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema**

El tema es que los datos subrayados en amarillo me gustaría mantenerlos del original. ¿Existe alguna opción que lo permita?

O la alternativa sería volver a generar los datos desde el índice.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Una forma muy fácil sería quitar el `fillna()` del `resample`, utiliar [`pandas.DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) (Que por cierto es un alias de `fillna()`) únicamente en las columnas que deseas conservar (Si quisieras conservar todas entonces puedes ponerlo directamente en el `resample`).

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'fecha_entrada': ['2021-01-01 00:25:24.027', '2021-01-01 06:53:57.853', '2021-01-01 10:07:32.817'],
        'fecha_salida': ['2021-01-01 11:58:23.247', '2021-01-01 15:24:50.710', '2021-01-01 11:49:27.727'],
        'length': [11.3259, 8.3053, 1.4155],
        'dia_semana': [4, 4, 4],
        'laborable': [0, 0, 0],
        'festivo': [1, 1, 1],
        'entrada': [1, 1, 1]}

datos = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(data['fecha_entrada']))
datos.index.name = 'fecha_entrada'

# Agrupar los datos por Hora
datos = datos.resample(
    rule = '1H',
    axis = 0,
    closed = "left" #Qué lado del intervalo bin se cierra. El valor predeterminado es "izquierda" para todos los desplazamientos de frecuencia excepto para "M", "A", "Q", "BM", "BA", "BQ" y "W", que tienen un valor predeterminado de "derecha".
    
).agg(
    {
        "fecha_entrada":"first",
        "fecha_salida":"last",
        "length":"sum",
        "entrada":"sum",
        "dia_semana":"first",
        "laborable":"first",
        "festivo":"first"
    }
)

# Rellenar hacia adelante
datos[['dia_semana', 'laborable', 'festivo']] = datos[['dia_semana', 'laborable', 'festivo']].ffill()

# Rellenar con 0 las demás columnas
datos.fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)

print(datos)
```

Esto imprime:

```
                               fecha_entrada             fecha_salida  \
fecha_entrada                                                           
2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 00:25:24.027  2021-01-01 11:58:23.247   
2021-01-01 01:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 02:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 03:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 04:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 05:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 06:00:00  2021-01-01 06:53:57.853  2021-01-01 15:24:50.710   
2021-01-01 07:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 08:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 09:00:00                        0                        0   
2021-01-01 10:00:00  2021-01-01 10:07:32.817  2021-01-01 11:49:27.727   

                      length  entrada  dia_semana  laborable  festivo  
fecha_entrada                                                          
2021-01-01 00:00:00  11.3259        1         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 01:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 02:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 03:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 04:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 05:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 06:00:00   8.3053        1         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 07:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 08:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 09:00:00   0.0000        0         4.0        0.0      1.0  
2021-01-01 10:00:00   1.4155        1         4.0        0.0      1.0
```

**Nota adicional:** Cuando publiques preguntas sobre `Python` intenta redactarla en su forma estandar, al parecer utilizas `JupyterLab` o algo similar (Ya que no pones los `print`) y si algún usuario no lo conoce entonces te pondrá comentarios de que el código no es correcto.